# Make a SVG transform matrix rotate around its center

Tags: javascript, math, matrix, svg, transform

HTML

```
<rect id="red" style="fill: red;" height="100" width="20"></rect>
```

JS

```
var layer = 
{  
    sizeReal   : { "width": 20, "height": 100 }                   
,   sizeScaled : { "width": 10, "height": 50 }
,   position   : { "x": 200, "y": 200 } 

,   scale      : 0.5
,   rotation   : 0
,   matrix     : [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
};

// Not sure if its the cleanest way but it works it rotates itself arounds its center.
//
$("#red")[0].setAttribute( 'transform', 'translate(' + layer.position.x + ',' + layer.position.y +') rotate(' + layer.rotation +',' + ( layer.sizeScaled.width  / 2 ) + ',' + ( layer.sizeScaled.height / 2 ) + ') scale(' + layer.scale + ',' + layer.scale +')' )
```

The example above changes the SVG rectangle by applying a transform.  I want to do the same, using a matrix. I'm using Sylvester to multiply the matrixes. I made a fiddle to make the question clear :)

http://jsfiddle.net/xYsHZ/3/

I want the red rect to behave the same as the green rect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!! the sequence of the matrix elements was wrong :)

```
$("#red")[0].setAttribute( 'transform', 'matrix(' + layer.matrix[ 0 ][ 0 ] + ',' + layer.matrix[ 1 ][ 0 ] + ',' + layer.matrix[ 0 ][ 1 ] + ',' + layer.matrix[ 1 ][ 1 ] + ',' + layer.matrix[ 0 ][ 2 ] + ',' + layer.matrix[ 1 ][ 2 ] + ')' );
},50);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6DR3D/2/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `rotate(angle, x, y)` call.
This call rotates at the given angle around the point (x,y).
But instead you build your matrix to rotate around layer.position.

In order to rotate around a given point (x,y), relative to the object, you need to first translate to (-x,-y), then rotate and then translate back to (x,y).

So if you had a matrix multiplication function Mul it might look something like this:

```
var m1 = GetMatrix(0, 0, {"x":-layer.sizeScaled.width/2, "y":-layer.sizeScaled.height/2});
var m2 = GetMatrix(layer.rotation, layer.scale, layer.position);
var m3 = GetMatrix(0, 0, {"x":layer.sizeScaled.width/2, "y":layer.sizeScaled.height/2});

var m = Mul(Mul(m3,m2), m1); //i.e. apply the matricdes in order m1, then m2, then m3
```

Comment: So i will basically have 3 matrixes applied to the svg element. Or does mul() combine the 3 into 1?

Comment: mul combines the three into one - it's just a multiplication of matrices