# SVG matrix transformation around point x,y

Tags: matrix, svg, transform

I try to make matrix `rotation`, `scale` and `skew` in `svg` but according/around to point `(x,y)`.

I try [Make a SVG transform matrix rotate around its center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663343/make-a-svg-transform-matrix-rotate-around-its-center/13665787#13665787) but it is working for me when object matrix is `[1,0,0,1,0,0]` = not edited yet. After I apply first `rotation` second is unpredictable and rotate all over the place.

Is there anyone who could help me with simple `rotation(ANGLE)`, `scaleX(NUMBER)`, `scaleX(NUMBER)`, `skewX(NUMBER)` and `skewY(NUMBER)` operations on matrix when matrix is already transformed and all depend on original point `x,y`?

Just remember that the matrix is already transformed and next modification will be from the next new matrix after this modification.

`matrix ( a: 0.9816080331802368, b:-0.1909615695476532, c: 0.1909615695476532, d: 0.9816080331802368, e: 120.33283996582031,f: -21.905738830566406)`

- So how is possible to transform matrix by rotate around some point `(x,y)`?
- how to scaleX,scaleY with point `(x,y)` and `skewX, skewY` as well with original transform in specific `(x,y)`?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convenient point for scale,rotate,skew of an element is to get the **center of its bounding box**. Use that point to first translate the element so its center point is at the origin, then apply the scale,or skew, or rotate, Then translate the element back to its original location.

To accomplish this via matrices uses:

1. A **matrix object** that holds all transform requests.
2. A **transform list** attached to the element to be transformed( a polygon in this example).
3. After each transform, **consolidate()** the transform list into a matrix.

This method uses object-generated methods to apply values, rather than building text-based attribute values..a lot cleaner.

Try this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='font-family:arial'>
<center>
(This example tested in: IE11/CH31/FF23)
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:8px;'>
Sequentially Transform an element about a fixed 'center point' in the element.
For this example, use the initial center of its bounding box.
</div>
<div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightblue;width:400px;height:400px;'>
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400">
<polygon id="myPolygon" fill="red" points="140,60 100,300 300,200 340,140" />
<circle id="centerPoint" r="4" fill="lime" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
</div>
<button onClick=rotate()>rotate</button>
<button onClick=scaleXY()>scaleXY</button>
<button onClick=skewX()>skewX</button>
<button onClick=skewY()>skewY</button>
<button onClick=startOver()>start over</button>
 <br />SVG Source:<br />
<textarea id=svgSourceValue style='font-size:110%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
</center>
</body>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{
    initTransform()
    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}

var Cx,Cy
var TransformRequestObj
var TransformList
//---onload---
function initTransform()
{
    var bb=myPolygon.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height
    Cx=bbx+.5*bbw
    Cy=bby+.5*bbh
    centerPoint.setAttribute("cx",Cx)
    centerPoint.setAttribute("cy",Cy)

    TransformRequestObj=mySVG.createSVGTransform()
    var animTransformList=myPolygon.transform
    TransformList=animTransformList.baseVal
}
//--button--
function rotate()
{
    var angle=10

    TransformRequestObj.setRotate(10,Cx,Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}
//---button---
function scaleXY()
{
    var scaleX=1.05
    var scaleY=1.05

    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(Cx,Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()
    TransformRequestObj.setScale(scaleX,scaleY)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()
    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(-Cx,-Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML

}
//---button---
function skewX()
{
    var skwX=5 //---deg

    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(Cx,Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    TransformRequestObj.setSkewX(skwX)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(-Cx,-Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

   svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}
//---button---
function skewY()
{
    var skwY=10 //---deg
    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(Cx,Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    TransformRequestObj.setSkewY(skwY)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(-Cx,-Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}
//---button---
function startOver()
{
    myPolygon.removeAttribute("transform")
    TransformRequestObj=mySVG.createSVGTransform()
    var animTransformList=myPolygon.transform
    TransformList=animTransformList.baseVal
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Genius , absolutely Genius, I spent over week and wasn't near that you achieve in 10 hours !!!!!
I am very new in SVG and Matrix modifications - but it is so powerful - I love it.

Thank you very much, just need to tweak little around to suite that I need but is look as it is all working !:)))

Comment: Is there any chance to store TransformList and then make modification base on this saved TransformList do not change only change last position ?

Like rotation is 20'

I would like add 35 and 44 so first time is showing 55 but second rotation not 55+44 but back to 20 and add this time 44 = 64.

Hope is clear !?

regards and thank you

Comment: You should be able to manipulate the values in the list. The list object has the following methods(see new answer()

Answer (score 0):

```
MyList.numberOfItems-Gets or sets the number of items in a list.
MyList.appendItem(newItem)-Inserts a new item at the end of the list.
MyList.clear()-Clears all existing items from the list, which creates an empty list.
MyList.getItem(index)-Returns the specified item from a list.
MyList.initialize(myItem)-Clears current items from the list and re-initializes the list to contain the specified item.
MyList.insertItemBefore(newItem,index)-Inserts a new item into a list at a specified position.
MyList.removeItem(myItem)-Removes an existing item from the list.
MyList.replaceItem(newItem,index)-Replaces a specified existing item in the list with a specified new item.
```

Transformations are additive, Non-matrix Transforms are just a long string. to see how this works don't use consolidate() and you will see the list as a string of requested transforms

Comment: as I am using  TransformList.consolidate() is not any more list I will believe, but as I have matrix save separate can I force matrix to animTransformList


TransformRequestObj=mySVG.createSVGTransform()

var animTransformList= {a:1,b:0,c:0,d:1,e:50,f:50}
TransformList=animTransformList.baseVal

Comment: Yes, I see you are understanding the process...good luck with your app.